# Pseudo "subdirectory subsite"

Tags: 7

While a real subdirectory subsite has a URL of `example.com/site1`, and shares codebase with `example.com`, I was wondering if it's possible to create a separate Drupal installation (in a separate docroot) for site1 and still use the URL `example.com/site1`. In my case, they are two completely different Drupal installations with nothing to share, well, except the somehow 'related' URL part.

I know I can just use a sub domain and make the whole thing a lot easier but am wondering if the pseudo 'subdirectory subsite' is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use an alias in your apache virtual host, something like this

```
Alias /site1 /path/to/your/site1
<Directory /path/to/your/site1>
  Options +Indexes 
  AllowOverride All 
</Directory>
```

Like it is suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055372/redirect-to-a-subfolder-in-apache-virtual-host-file#19055573

Comment: Thanks! That's easy enough :) As a follow up question, do you know is it possible to do something similar using Drupal's .htaccess file (or other Drupal config files)? I have a site with Acquia and I don't have access to these .conf files there.

Comment: I don't think so, rewrite rules in .htaccess work only in the root directory of your page, so you can't redirect outside it. Maybe you could redirect the whole subdirectory to some php file and then use php to redirect it, but i haven't tried it. You could use Drupal redirect module and redirect url www.example.com/site1 to some subdomain where your other drupal site lives.